# How to make a file type (.blend) association when it does not appear in Properties > Open With? (16.04 LTS)

Tags: unity, .desktop, blender, file-association, file-properties

The file type association for .blend files broke after I removed the synaptic version of blender and installed the official blender site version. I also tried the Thomas Schiex PPA. The association is still broken even returning to the synaptic version. I have checked the following:

- I do have a good *blender.desktop* file in */usr/share/applications*. Yes, it does have a *%f* flag on *Exec*.
- *RMB -> open with other application* -> view all -> No option for blender
- *RMB -> properties* -> open with -> No option for blender
- After messing with this for an hour I caved and went to */usr/share/applications/defaults.list* and inserted the line *application/x-blender=blender.desktop*

This last line seems to work for associating the .blend file type, but double-clicking any .blend file opens Blender with a terminal that says:

> Read prefs: /home/user/.config/blender/2.79/config/userpref.blend
>
> Read blend: /home/user/Desktop/audio_visualizer.blend

Each time I open a file another terminal opens with the blender window. Ideally, how can I make blender appear as an option in the properties "open-with" menu? Else, how do I make blender open from a file without a terminal window opening too?

---

In case it's helpful, here's the blender.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Blender
GenericName=3D modeler
GenericName[ar]=3D ﺎﻠﻤﻨﻣﺬﺟ ﺙﻼﺜﻳ ﺍﻸﺒﻋﺍﺩ
GenericName[ca]=Modelador 3D
GenericName[cs]=3D modelování
GenericName[da]=3D-modellering
GenericName[de]=3D-Modellierer
GenericName[el]=Μοντελοποιητής 3D
GenericName[es]=Modelador 3D
GenericName[et]=3D modelleerija
GenericName[fi]=3D-mallintaja
GenericName[fr]=Modeleur 3D
GenericName[gl]=Modelador 3D
GenericName[hu]=3D modellező
GenericName[it]=Modellatore 3D
GenericName[ja]=3D モデラー
GenericName[lt]=3D modeliavimas
GenericName[nb]=3D-modellering
GenericName[nl]=3D-modeller
GenericName[pl]=Modelowanie 3D
GenericName[pt_BR]=Modelador 3D
GenericName[ro]=Arhitect 3D
GenericName[ru]=Редактор 3D-моделей
GenericName[tr]=3D modelleyici
GenericName[uk]=Редактор 3D-моделей
GenericName[wa]=Modeleu 3D
GenericName[zh_CN]=3D 建模
GenericName[zh_TW]=3D 模型
Comment=3D modeling, animation, rendering and post-production
Comment[ar]=3D ﺎﻠﻨﻣﺬﺟﺓ، ﺎﻟﺮﺳﻮﻣ ﺎﻠﻤﺘﺣﺮﻛﺓ، ﻭﺎﻠﺘﺠﺴﻳﺩ، ﻮﻣﺍ ﺐﻋﺩ ﺍﻺﻨﺗﺎﺟ
Comment[ast]=Modeláu 3D, animación, renderizáu y postproducción
Comment[eu]=3D modelatzea, animazioa, errendatzea eta post-produkzioa
Comment[be]=Праграма прасторавага мадэлявання, анімацыі, апрацоўкі відэа і давядзення відэапрадукцыі
Comment[bn]=ত্রিমাত্রিক মডেল, অ্যানিমেশন, রেন্ডারিং এবং পোস্ট-উৎপাদন
Comment[bs]=3D modeliranje, animacija, obrada i postprodukcija
Comment[bg]=3D моделиране, анимиране, рендиране и пост-продукция
Comment[ca]=Modelat 3D, animació, renderització i post-producció
Comment[ca@valencia]=Modelat 3D, animació, renderització i post-producció
Comment[crh]=3B modelleme, animasyon, işleme ve son üretim
Comment[cs]=3D modelování, animace, rederování a postprodukce
Comment[da]=3D-modellering, animation, rendering og efterbehandling
Comment[de]=3D-Modellierung, Animation, Rendering und Nachbearbeitung
Comment[nl]=3d-modelleren, animeren, renderen en post-productie
Comment[el]=Μοντελοποίηση 3D, κινούμενα σχέδια, αποτύπωση και οργάνωση διαδικασίας μετά-την-παραγωγή
Comment[eo]=3D-modelado, animacio, renderado kaj postproduktado
Comment[es]=Modelado 3D, animación, renderizado y post-producción
Comment[et]=Kolmemõõtmeline modelleerimine, animeerimine, esitlemine ja järeltöötlemine
Comment[fi]=3D-mallinnus, -animaatiot, -renderöinti ja -tuotanto
Comment[fr]=Modélisation 3D, animation, rendu et post-production
Comment[fr_CA]=Modélisation 3D, animation, rendu et post-production
Comment[gl]=Modelado 3D, animación, renderizado e postprodución
Comment[hu]=3D modellek és animációk létrehozása és szerkesztése
Comment[is]=Þrívíddarmódel, hreyfimyndir, myndgerð og frágangur myndskeiða
Comment[it]=Modellazione 3D, animazione, rendering e post-produzione
Comment[ja]=3Dモデリング、アニメーション、レンダリング、ポストプロダクションのツ
ール
Comment[ko]=3D 모델링, 애니메이션, 렌더링과 포스트 프로덕션
Comment[lt]=3D modeliavimas, animacijų kūrimas, atvaizdavimas ir tobulinimas
Comment[lv]=3D modelēšana, animācija, renderēšana un pēcapstrāde
Comment[ms]=Pemodelan, animasi, penerapan dan post-produksi 3D
Comment[nb]=3D-modellering, animasjon, rendering og postproduksjon
Comment[oc]=Modelizacion 3D, animacion, rendut e post-produccion
Comment[pl]=Modelowanie 3D, animacja, renderowanie i postprodukcja
Comment[pt]=Modelação 3D, animação, renderização e pós-produção
Comment[pt_BR]=Modelagem 3D, animação, renderização e pós-produção
Comment[ro]=Modelare, animare, afișare și post-producție 3D
Comment[ru]=3D-моделирование, анимация, рендеринг и компоновка
Comment[sl]=3D modeliranje, animacija, izrisovanje in nadaljnje obdelovanje
Comment[sq]=Animacion i modeleve 3D, rregullim dhe më pas prodhim
Comment[sr]=3Д моделовање, анимација, исцртавање и постпродукција
Comment[sv]=3d-modellering, animering, rendering och efterbehandling
Comment[ta]=முப்பரிமாண ஒப்புருவாக்கம், அசைவூட்டம், காட்சியாக்கம் மற்றும் உருவாக்கத்துக்கு பிந்தைய செயல்பாடுகள்
Comment[tg]=Моделсозии 3D, аниматсия, пешниҳод ва истеҳсоли баъдӣ
Comment[tr]=3B modelleme, animasyon, işleme ve son üretim
ння відеопродуктівма просторового моделювання, анімації, обробки відео та доведеComment[vi]=Tạo hình mẫu 3D, hoạt họa, dựng hình và các công việc hậu kỳ
Comment[wa]=Modelaedje 3D, animåcion, rindou eyet après-produccion
Comment[zh_HK]=3D 模型、動畫、算圖和後製
Comment[zh_CN]=3D 建模、动画、渲染和后期制作
Comment[zh_TW]=3D 模型、動畫、算圖和後製
Keywords=3d;cg;modeling;animation;painting;sculpting;texturing;video editing;video tracking;rendering;render engine;cycles;game engine;python;
Exec=blender %f
Icon=blender
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Graphics;3DGraphics;
MimeType=application/x-blender;
```

Comment: Look at [`desktop-file-utils`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils/) or [`shared-mime-info`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/shared-mime-info/) to build/adjust the application bindings. The new terminal windows will be opening as you have `Terminal=true` in your desktop file, change to false to stop that.

Comment: george and sambler, thank you. Using mimeopen and changing to Terminal=true in blender.desktop fixed this.